# Is there some generic algorithm to calculate the dimensions of a piece of fabric needed to cover a 3D shape

Tags: algorithm, three.js

I hope that this is the correct place to ask this kind of question. I am developing a web app to design garden ponds and I need to calculate the shape and size of the foil needed to cover that pond. The pond will provided as a 3D model (threeJS). The shape of the pond will be relatively simple (think one or more rectangular boxes potentially with some stairs).

I am considering folding out the surface of the 3D model into a flat shape, but I do not know how to do that in a generic way. And even if a could od that it would not be the complete solution (but potentially it would be a starting point) I have been searching for a generic algorithm to do this, but so far have not found anything. Does anyone know of an algorithm that I could use for this, or at least something that I could start with.

Some additonal information:

- this will be a browser based solution which should show the pool; one option would be ThreeJS since I am somewhat familiar with it
- the foil that should cover the pond needs to watertight, so it needs to be one piece. That means that when your put it in the pool, it form rinkle, especially in the corners.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also add example about what kind of input you have and what output you would need out of it.

Comment: I don't think Three.js has a way to do this for you. If your pond is made up of rectangular boxes, just take the surface area of each square and add them up. If your custom model is more complex, I recommend you use a 3D editing tool, like Blender, to [calculate the surface area of any geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13975)

Comment: @libik, the input is the goemetry of the pool, in its simplest form just a rectangular hole in the ground, but the shapes can be more complicated (sloping sides, multiple conected rectangles etc.). The output should be the shape in which a a flat piece of foil needs to cut, so that it can covers the pool (bottom and sides). Note that the foil will not be flat everywhere; in corners there will be wrinkles and in places it may be bunched up.

Comment: @Marquizzo, I am considering ThreeJS because this is for an editor that shows a 3D model of the pool,. AlsoThreeJS has at least some utilitzy functions that can calculate intersections and the like. Just adding the surface of the bottom and sides is not enough because in corners the material will be double; otherwise the foil is not watertight.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I don't think three.js can do this work for you. You'd have to calculate the areas yourself via JavaScript. Your case seems pretty unique, especially since 90° edges would require less fabric than a 270° edge, and other such cases. Three.js simply doesn't have this functionality built into it.